# Shared SQL ID trace

Tags: sql-server

Have an ID that uses SQL authentication, unfortunately there are multiple users sharing this ID; I want to see the host name of each client that uses this ID.

Been playing around with trace (default), anyone else deal with this?

I’d like to go back as far as possible; bunch of error logs are there but trace only has most recent file, not all 5 files

Comment: The root of your problem is right here, "unfortunately there are multiple users sharing this ID".

Comment: Yes, but things are a changing

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about all 5 files but if the data you are looking for is in the trace and it is no longer there...well....you could setup an extended events session or check the default trace more frequently.

Comment: 5 trc files saved default and older are now archived, need some historical info  all have are logs and one trc

Comment: FYI - just did a query on sys.sysprocesses  and joined with sys.databases and wrote to a table; this is for future; the past was basically lost as mentioned above,  and just to point this out:  comments like this < The root of your problem is right here, "unfortunately there are multiple users sharing this ID" > are not helpful

Comment: Useful or not that is a major problem. You should have different users instead of sharing them.

Comment: No kidding captain obvious!  It was unfortunately there were multiple users sharing the ID, that was fixed and I was trying to go back and research and the trace files were gone

Comment: I guess I was just supposed to assume you knew that? Nothing in your post suggested that. Forgive me for offering any advice. Regardless glad you figured out a way to find the information you were looking for.

Comment: Thank You, I guess I usually assume people will answer the questions asked   <<'I want to see the host name of each client that uses this ID. Been playing around with trace (default), anyone else deal with this?:>>
and Thanks for your advice = "The root of your problem is right here, "unfortunately there are multiple users sharing this ID". "  It was a real eye opener and really helped me!

Comment: Often the questions asked are not really the issue but a result of something else. I jumped to that conclusion here too quickly.